# Error when pip installing apache-flink due to numpy

Tags: python, pip, apache-flink, apple-m1, pyflink

I'm trying to install Apache Flink with either `python3 -m pip install apache-flink` or `pip3 install apache-flink`, but both fail with an exit code 1 error:

```
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
            error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
      
      × Encountered error while trying to install package.
      ╰─> numpy
      
      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

The output is quite long so I won't post the whole thing here, but if there's something in particular I should be looking for in there, any suggestions are welcome.

I've also tried starting with numpy already installed in a hope that apache-flink would just use the installed version but that didn't help.

`pip3 --version` ->
`pip 22.1.2 from /Users/sophier/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

I'm on the new mac with the M1 chip incase that could be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyFlink on a M1 is not yet supported but will be from Flink 1.16 onwards, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25188

Comment: I still have a similar issue with apache-flink 1.16 with poetry because of numpy version incompatibility between pemja requirement and apache-flink requirement on numpy -> ```
Because pemja (0.2.6) depends on numpy (1.21.4)
 and apache-flink (1.16.0) depends on numpy (>=1.14.3,<1.20), pemja (0.2.6) is incompatible with apache-flink (1.16.0).```

Comment: That Poetry problem will be improved with Flink 1.16.1, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29817

Comment: Any chance to know a release date? Or to have a clue on this? Thanks

Comment: I would suspect in the next couple of weeks, probably at the end of this year/beginning of next year.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnVisser. 
Do you know if there is another way to run PyFlink on M1 while waiting?
And do you know what the next Flink release is going to be 1.16.1 or 1.17.0?

Comment: Any update on this? I am unable to run pyflink on M1. Is there any alternative method?

Comment: The discussion on Flink 1.16.1 has been started, I expect that will be released at the end of this month

Comment: Flink 1.16.1 is now available

Comment: Thank you @MartijnVisser I am trying to work with Flink 1.16.1. Do you by any chance have any Dockerfile examples with a Flink 1.16.1 image that also contain some RUN commands regarding installing python in the container? Like RUN apt install -y python3.8 python3-pip python3.8-dev? I believe python <3.10 is required for pyflink?

Comment: Interesting, installing apache-flink==1.15.4 with Python3.7 works for me on M1.

Comment: The problem seems to exist, I use Python3.11.6 and tried to install apache-flink 1.18.0 and still get "No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.4" I guess it is caused by pemja 0.3.0